Clicking on a url link in a code block evaluates instead of opening the link
I have some code blocks in my org file which have url links inside them, but clicking on them evaluates the codeblock and returns the result in the *Messages* buffer (similar to C-x C-e for eval-last-sexp) instead of opening the link.
Is this expected behaviour?
How can I make emacs open the link instead of evaluating?

Below is an example code block
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
;; this is an example url: http://google.com/
(+ 12 27)
#+end_src


This has been reported & discussed in the org-mode repo here, which also has a suggestion (see below). But it also mentions that the suggestion is not reliable for code blocks in all languages. And this is also from 2019. Has there been any change this behaviour or is there any better solution for this?

Suggested workaround
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (defun org-follow-link-in-src-block-hook ()
    (and
     (eq 'src-block (org-element-type (org-element-context)))
     (let ((link-be (org-in-regexp org-any-link-re)))
       (if link-be
       (org-open-link-from-string
        (buffer-substring-no-properties (car link-be)
                        (cdr link-be))))
       link-be)))
  (add-hook 'org-open-at-point-functions 'org-follow-link-in-src-block-hook)
#+end_src


Good question.  The problem seems to be in the function org-open-at-point.

Can you please fix the link to point to the specific thread on the mailing list?

AFAIK, that is expected behavior. If you call org-element-at-point while point is on the URL inside the code block, the  result is not link, it is src-block. You would have to modify the parser to recognize links inside src blocks. ATM, they are just strings. But I would like to read the discussion that you found on the ML, hence my request for a better link.

@NickD, updated the link to the thread, I didn't realize it was not correct
